# Different colors on the same polygon in 3D view of QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, 3d, 3d-map

I have a .shp file with buildings represented as polygons.

[image: Top view]

[image: 3D]

My goal is that, in a 3D representation, I am able to have different colors in a single polygon (building) depending on its height. For example, from 0 to 10 meters, buildings are yellow, then from 10 to 20 m they are blue, and so on.
Is there any way of doing this in QGIS or using PyQGIS?
I have tried to add copies of the buildings to the shapefile with different heights and the number of copies depends on the height of the building, and then pick a different color for each building copy, but it does not work, still only one color appears.

EDIT: This is an exemplification of what I'm looking for:
[image: Example]

EDIT2: Using the Properties > 3D View > Rule-based, and then View > New 3D Map View, I get a 2D map :( :
[image: new 3d map view]

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting rule based 3d rendering. Navigate to Properties > 3D View > Rule-based and create your own rules and styling.

I did this really quick crude example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you visualize the 3D map?

Comment: In QGIS go to View > New 3D Map View

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it still shows in 2D

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using and can you show a screenshot of the 3D view

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.6.3

Comment: Hold your scroll wheel in and move your mouse to change your viewing angle

Comment: Still no 3D view...